# UIScrollView With UICollectionView

Tags: uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have UIScrollView And UICollectionView. In CollectionView ther are 25 images of 100x100 size. When I run my application its display the first 12 images in the simulator then I scroll up then its display the next images. that is not my problem. I want to display Images in horizontal mode not in vertical mode . means in first page its display the 12 images then scroll horizontal and its display the next images not in vertical.please tell me how to do it.

Thanks.

```
#import "Collection.h"
#import "PageViewController.h"

@interface Collection ()

@end

@implementation Collection

@synthesize collView,selectedAlbum,img1;

static NSString *const cellReuseIdentifier = @"CollectionViewCell";

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self.collView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewItem" bundle:nil]     forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier];
    self.collView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:10];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:10];
   // [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [collView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
     collView.delegate = self;

    //Customize scrollView

    scrolView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrolView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400);
    scrolView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:scrolView];
    scrolView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,0,640,450);
    [scrolView addSubView:collView];

    Images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3(3).jpg",@"baby1.jpg",@"Baby2.jpg",@"Baby3.jpg",@"boat_sea_beach-normal.jpg",@"cool.jpg",@"gold-iphone-5-300912.jpg",@"life-sometimes.jpg",@"Mac Wallpapers.jpeg",@"Quotes.jpg",@"series.jpg",@"wallpaper.jpg",@"wide-9.jpg", nil];
    }

    self.navigationItem.title = selectedAlbum;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return Images.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell1 = [collView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIImageView *imageImages = (UIImageView *) [cell1 viewWithTag:16];
    imageImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell1;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace your (commented)scrolldirection with this:

[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];